# How can I store a software installation dvd on HD/SSD?

Tags: storage

I searched online how to store/rip a software dvd to hard disk, but all the hits I get on google refer to dvd ripping software that are specifically for movies. *E.g.*, [PC magazine](https://www.pcmag.com/feature/362347/the-best-free-dvd-rippers) gives a list of 3 options, including the freeware tool Handbrake (which actually looks pretty cool to store movies). I also skimmed this site and couldn't find my answer.

However, I'm not too interested in storing my movies at this time; I have a stack of software I wish to store on HD as the dvds are getting older and they are behaving iffy. Also dvd players are slowly phased out I guess.

**Are there tools to store software installer dvds on HD / SSD?**. I'm using Win10 on a 46 bit system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many circumstances, "simply" copying over the contents of the disk might work, assuming the software doesn't have some sort of disk based copy protection method. I often back up software installations this way.

Alternatively, you need to find a tool that would let you image it as an ISO. I've traditionally used imgburn - you load the disk into your optical drive, and the read option should let you dump it out to an ISO file. You can then natively load this into windows. I don't actually have any optical drives on hand so I can't do a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks, I'm, trying the simple copy to SSD as we speak! 3 minutes and I can accept your swift answer ;-)

Comment: That seemed to work like a dream! I wish life would always be this simple.